# What is the Ubuntu colour?

Tags: colors, design

I'm sure you know the one I'm talking about, that deep magenta.  I would like to know it's RGB value.

Comment: Technically the Ubuntu color is orange. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All the colors, graphics, and layout details for Ubuntu can be found in the [Ubuntu Design brand assets](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/).

From [the colour palette page](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette) you'll find that:

The Purple (CANONICAL AUBERGINE) is `#772953`
The Orange (UBUNTU ORANGE) is `#e95420`

Comment: In particular, the third and fifth pages of [this document](http://design.canonical.com/brand/5.%20Ubuntu%20colour%20palettes%20and%20colour%20landscape.pdf) probably have what you want.

Comment: may i know it in the values of how much red green blue because i can not set # va

Comment: The RGB color code is 48, 10, 36: https://codeyarns.com/2013/01/21/default-background-color-of-terminal-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

RGB colour code for Purple(aubergine) is 119,41,83. That's Red: 119, Green: 41 and Blue: 83

Ubuntu Orange is 221,72,20. That's Red: 221, Green: 72 and Blue: 20.

Answer (score 0):

The links are out of date. I'd suggest [trying this](https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette).  It is the official colour palette for Ubuntu.

I also found out that 69 69 69 is ubuntu's ambiance dark grey and 174 167 159 is ubuntu's light grey