# Ubuntu 20.04 Grub colour is black and white

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

I recently installed **Ubuntu 20.04** on a dual boot with **Windows 10** but from the start the grub boot loader is black and white. Now it's not much of a problem because the operating systems itself work alright but I think I would rather choose to stare at a purple screen at the start rather than a black and white one.

Thanks for any solutions .

Comment: you may choose your own color or have a idea with this https://askubuntu.com/q/69271/739431

Comment: I Just check the above link.. in 20.04 there is no file `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub`. so crete the `default.grub` file first. and then copy paste the if;then;fi concept colors from the answers. I checked it. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

[grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) is a tool that allows you to easy customize your Grub menu. You should give it a shot ! :)

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find difficulty in understanding  [Duplicate Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47488/how-to-change-the-purple-background-color-in-grub)

copy paste the below in a empty text file in home directory and name the file as `grub.sh`.
save the file & close.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub

touch $file
echo "if background_color 66,30,53 ; then
   clear
fi" > $file

update-grub
```

and run the command

```
sudo bash grub.sh
```

[image]

Reboot will show you purple background for grub menu screen.